# How to output to pdf using knitr/xtable when tex has square braces ( [ )?

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, xtable

I am trying to output the freq table generated by `cut` to a PDF file using knitr and xtable. However, when I include the option `include.rownames=FALSE` the output is not processed and an error is reported whereas the code works with `include.rownames=TRUE`. Test code is below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

<<test_table, results = "asis",echo=FALSE>>=
library(xtable)
x <- sample(10,100,replace=TRUE)
breaks <- c(1,2,5,10)
x.freq <- data.frame(table(cut(x, breaks, right=FALSE)))
print(xtable(x.freq),include.rownames=TRUE)
@

\end{document}
```

When I use `include.rownames=TRUE` I get the output below.

> 1 [1,2) 5
>   2 [2,5) 35
>   3 [5,10) 49

whereas when I use `include.rownames=FALSE` I get an error:

> Test.tex:71: LaTeX Error: \begin{tabular} on input line 58 ended by \end{document}.

I believe that I am getting the error because of the presence of the square braces ' [ ' in the text source.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: One simple manual workaround would be to provide `labels` to your `cut` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the end of each row in the table is a `\\` which has an optional argument to specify how much space to leave before the next row, for example, `\\[1in]`.  There's allowed to be white space between the `\\` and the `[`, so in this case, it's trying to read the `[2,5)` as that argument.

A simple workaround would be to change the labels of the factor to include some non-printing blank character first, however, if you do so, by default, `print.xtable` will "sanitize" it so that it actually does print, so you'd need to turn that off by passing a new sanitize function; `identity` will do none of this fixing.

```
levels(x.freq$Var1) <- paste0("{}", levels(x.freq$Var1))
print(xtable(x.freq),include.rownames=FALSE, sanitize.text=identity)
```

Comment: A typo- I suppose you meant `include.rownames=FALSE`, right? The solution worked flawlessly.